# Можно ли объявить один класс в другом и если нет, то как можно иначе это реализовать?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++

Допустим, у меня есть два класса: A и B. Мне нужно, чтобы в классе A можно было было бы иметь несколько классов B. Я пробовал сделать это так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
private:
int x;
int y;
int z;
B op1;
B op2("square", 2);
B op3("qwerty", 5);
B op4("abc", 7);
B op5;
public:
    A()
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
        z = 1;
    }

    A(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }

    int productNumbers()
    {
        return x * y * z;   
    }

    void printProfuctNumbers()
    {
        op1.printInfo();
        cout << x * y * z;
    }
};

class B
{
private:
string nameOperation;
int numberOperation;
public:
    B()
    {
        nameOperation = "Multiplication";
        numberOperation = 1;
    }

    B(string str, int num)
    {
        nameOperation = str;
        numberOperation = num;
    }

    void printInfo()
    {
        cout << endl << nameOperation << ' ' << numberOperation << " : ";   
    }
};

int main()
{
    A Multi;
    cout << Multi.productNumbers() << endl << endl;

    Multi.printProfuctNumbers();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор соответственно ругается на строчки с op1..op5.
Просто мне нужно, чтобы из класса А можно было создавать и получать данные из классов B, при этом, чтобы класс А имел несколько таких классов B. По сути я хотел в одном из конструкторов класса А произвести реализацию класса B, то есть сделать примерно так:

```
...
class A
{
private:
int x;
int y;
int z;
string nameOperation1;
int numberOperation1;
string nameOperation2;
int numberOperation2;
string nameOperation3;
int numberOperation3;
string nameOperation4;
int numberOperation4;
string nameOperation5;
int numberOperation5;
public:
...
```

, но подумал, что будет удобнее вынести эти переменные в класс B (если брать реальную ситуацию, то их было гораздо больше).

Пробовал переносить объявление классов B в конструктор класса А, всё равно были ошибки.

Скорее всего эту проблему можно решить при помощи либо дружественных классов, либо наследования классов, но мне тяжело разобраться, как работает эта логика.

Comment: https://ideone.com/UybtDk да нормально всё работает)

Comment: Действительно, если перенести реализацию класса B поверх А, то уже на "B op1;" компилятор не ругается, но если встречается "B op2("square", 2);" - компилятор сообщает:

"37:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
37:7: error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant".

Получается, нужно в B добавлять дополнительные методы для инициализации переменных нужными данными?

Comment: Не какие-то "дополнительные методы", а **конструктор(ы)**!!!

Comment: Я имел ввиду другое. Раз при помощи конструктора один класс в другом инициализировать не получилось - первое, что приходит на ум - создать метод в классе B, например, void setNameOperation(string str) или void setNumberOperation(int n) - это уже методы будут же

Comment: https://ideone.com/mO6OqP

Comment: А, ну так для значений по умолчанию используйте фигурные скобки... https://ideone.com/wUyAYy

Comment: Теперь проблем нет. Всё работает. Большое спасибо вам всем за помощь!